# how to use sed to replace a special string a carrige return

Tags: sed, carriage-return

If I want to replace the `AAA` in a line `abcAAA` with carriage return `^M`, how can I do using sed, or some other command line stream editor?

input:

```
123
123AAA
123
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with `sed -e 's/AAA/^M/g' <inputfile >outputfile` where `^M` is ctrl-V ctrl-M.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
sed 's/^\(abc\)AAA$/\1\x0D/'
```

Comment: Looking at the *input:* in the question, I think *abc* is a place-holder for three characters rather than a literal. Then again, *specification by example* is always problematic.